# Using outer query ID in a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a list of invoices with there statuses and reported date, let's say each date we have new report could change the invoice status from PENDING to PAID. I want subquery the first date an invoice was paid for each invoice. The table looks like this:

| invoice_id | report_date | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 08-26-2021 | PAID |
| A2 | 08-26-2021 | PENDING |
| A3 | 08-26-2021 | PENDING |
| A4 | 08-26-2021 | PENDING |
| A1 | 08-28-2021 | PAID |
| A2 | 08-28-2021 | PENDING |
| A3 | 08-28-2021 | PAID |
| A4 | 08-28-2021 | PENDING |
| A1 | 08-30-2021 | PAID |
| A2 | 08-30-2021 | PENDING |
| A3 | 08-30-2021 | PAID |
| A4 | 08-30-2021 | PENDING |

I have a query like:

```
SELECT 
  invoice_id,
  report_date,
  status,
  CASE status
     WHEN 'PAID' THEN
        (SELECT report_date FROM invoices WHERE invoice_id = #INVOICE_REF_ID
         AND status = 'PAID' ORDER BY report_date LIMIT 1)
  END AS paid_date
FROM invoices
```

I expect something like:

| invoice_id | report_date | status | paid_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 08-26-2021 | PAID | 08-26-2021 |
| A2 | 08-26-2021 | PENDING |  |
| A3 | 08-26-2021 | PENDING |  |
| A4 | 08-26-2021 | PENDING |  |
| A1 | 08-28-2021 | PAID | 08-26-2021 |
| A2 | 08-28-2021 | PENDING |  |
| A3 | 08-28-2021 | PAID | 08-28-2021 |
| A4 | 08-28-2021 | PENDING |  |
| A1 | 08-30-2021 | PAID | 08-26-2021 |
| A2 | 08-30-2021 | PENDING |  |
| A3 | 08-30-2021 | PAID | 08-28-2021 |
| A4 | 08-30-2021 | PENDING |  |

I need to know what should I replace #INVOICE_REF_ID so it references the invoice_id selected in the parent query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include table aliases in your subquery, you would be able to achieve this. In the sample below I have assigned the alias `main_inv` to the outer query

```sql
SELECT 
  invoice_id,
  report_date,
  status,
  CASE status
     WHEN 'PAID' THEN
        (SELECT report_date FROM invoices WHERE invoice_id = main_inv.invoice_id
         AND status = 'PAID' ORDER BY report_date LIMIT 1)
  END AS paid_date
FROM invoices main_inv
```

Since you are using postgresql, you could also achieve this with a window function `MIN` eg

```sql
SELECT 
  invoice_id,
  report_date,
  status,
  CASE 
      WHEN status='PAID' THEN MIN(report_date) OVER (PARTITION BY invoice_id,status)
  END AS paid_date
FROM invoices
```

Let me know if this works for you.